# Could not handle ?university dbpedia-owl:count in ARC2

Tags: php, sparql, dbpedia

I'm using simple SPARQL query to get a list of universities for selected country. 
and that some of SPARQL code

```
SELECT ?name ?type 
WHERE 
  {   ?university  a                    <http://schema.org/CollegeOrUniversity>
    { ?university  dbpedia-owl:country  dbpedia:France }
    UNION
    { ?university  dbpprop:country      dbpedia:France }
    OPTIONAL
    { ?university  dbpprop:name         ?name          .
         FILTER (LANGMATCHES(LANG(?name), 'fr'))       }
    OPTIONAL
    { ?university  dbpedia-owl:type     ?type          }
```

To show a result in PHP side, I'm using [ARC2 library](http://cui.unige.ch/isi/icle-wiki/php_sparql_endpoints) to use PHP to query SPARQL endpoints and generate HTML pages.  All steps from the doc is ok.

Here that full PHP code with SPARQL query server side:

```
<html>
  <body>

  <?php
  include_once('semsol/ARC2.php'); /* ARC2 static class inclusion */ 

  $dbpconfig = array(
  "remote_store_endpoint" => "http://dbpedia.org/sparql",
   );

  $store = ARC2::getRemoteStore($dbpconfig); 

  if ($errs = $store->getErrors()) {
     echo "<h1>getRemoteSotre error<h1>" ;
  }

  $query = '
        PREFIX     foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
        PREFIX       dc:  <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1>
        PREFIX      rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
        PREFIX  address:  <http://www.w3.org/Addressing/schemes.html>
        PREFIX     rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>


      SELECT ?name ?type 
             WHERE {
                       ?university  a                     <http://schema.org/CollegeOrUniversity>
                     { ?university  dbpedia-owl:country   dbpedia:France }
                   UNION
                     { ?university  dbpprop:country       dbpedia:France }
                   OPTIONAL
                     { ?university  dbpprop:name          ?name          .
                          FILTER (LANGMATCHES(LANG(?name), 'fr'))        }
                   OPTIONAL
                     { ?university  dbpedia-owl:type      ?type          }  
                   }
             ORDER BY ?name
          ';


  $rows = $store->query($query, 'rows'); /* execute the query */

  if ($errs = $store->getErrors()) {
     echo "Query errors" ;
     print_r($errs);
  }

  /* display the results in an HTML table */
  echo "<table border='1'>" ;
  foreach( $rows as $row ) { /* loop for each returned row */
         print "<tr><td>" .$row['l'] . "</td><td>" . $row['c']. "</td></tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>"

  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

but when I run my code on server side that's error handling

> `Query errorsArray ( [0] => Incomplete or invalid Group Graph pattern. Could not handle " ?university dbpedia-owl:count" in ARC2_SPARQLPlusParser [1] => Incomplete or invalid Group Graph pattern. Could not handle " { ?univers" in ARC2_SPARQLPlusParser )`

So is there any solution? Many thanks

Comment: Just a question: do the single quotes around 'fr' break the string holding the query, since it's also in single quotes?

Comment: Yes mr. single quotes around 'fr'

Comment: Did the answer below prove sufficient?  Please mark it as accepted if so.  If not...  Please edit your question to reflect what you've done to find it not sufficient, any new error messages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't include the prefixes for **dbpedia-owl**, **dbpedia** or **dbpprop**.  When you use the web service interactively, these are defined automatically, but when you connect remotely, you still need to include them.  You can see the [full list of prefixes](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl) that get defined in the browser.

I'd *guess* that's what's happening is that when you get to **dbpedia-owl:count** it realizes that it's seen **count**, which is a legal SPARQL keyword, and then realizes that **dbpedia-owl:** didn't make sense.  (I'm not familiar with ARC's parser, though;  this is just a guess.)

I expect that you may also run into issues by doing:

```
$query = '...'fr'...';
```

I'm not a PHP user, so I'm not certain how that's handled, but it *looks* like those single quotes need to be escaped, or that you need to use double quotes.

Comment: I do notice that `dbpedia-owl:count` doesn't exist in the query; that's a truncation of `country`... but I think the general idea is likely correct -- that the prefix declarations are the key, and that the `...'fr'...` single-quotes need to be escaped within the PHP codeblock.